# Git merge strategies for Kanban, production support, environment

Tags: git, git-merge

We are currently re-evaluating our git merge strategy. Our current workflow for our existing "production support" projects is thus:

1. When you start development, you create your branch from the project `develop` branch.
2. When the work is finished, the code goes through a `pull request` back into the `develop` branch. This `develop` is a `CICD` branch, so that once a `pull request` goes through, all of those changes are testable in our development environment.
3. Once the work has been tested and the business team is ready for it to go to production, it is then `cherry-picked` into a branch that then gets merged into the `master` branch.

This seems to work for a while. However, sometimes a feature becomes lower priority, especially if a feature is buggy and the original developer has been already assigned to a higher priority task, we end up with a situation where our `master` branch is 100+ `behind` AND 100+ `ahead`. This means that the longer we go the less and less `master` looks like `develop`, and worse, and as time goes on it seems that the merges tend to cause more and more frequent and complex `merge conflicts`. The pain here has become acute enough to where we need a better solution.

I've looked at various strategies, especially the `Feature Branch` strategy, but I am concerned about some of the pieces of this, for example, how can we have a `CICD` branch with such a strategy... does each developer need a new development environment for each feature? What about features that build on top of other features, is there a good way to track such dependencies? Is there any other, better, way to manage our code churn without the pain? Don't know that it matters, but we use `ASP.NET/C#`.

Comment: To me it seems that feature branches should not be rooted at `develop`, but on `master`. Then they can be merged into both master and develop without cherry-picking the commits. Then `master` will not be ahead of `develop`, but just behind.

Comment: You're trying to solve the real problems with branching and merging, but too many bugs and constantly changing priorities can't be solved by cherry-picking. This could possibly be solved by branching by abstraction in your code, feature toggles may help, but the best solution is to make work smaller and increase the quality so everything that's done can immediately go to production. Whatever you do, I recommed getting rid of your develop branch if the intent is to continuously deliver Kanban style. Fewer branches is better.

Comment: When practicing Kanban there's a concept of "the point of commitment", once past it, which you've crossed once you really start the development work, possible earlier. This concept represents the commitment of the customer and the developers to either: deliver the feature as quickly as possible *or* decide to abandon the feature completely including the work to remove the feature from the code. There's noreally no "let's stop this now and do it some other time" option where the unfinished code is in the way of delivering new Veire valuable work.

Comment: Even Kanban has a few rules and requires some real discipline to work smoothly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider:

### 1. Trunk Based Development with Master as the Single Mainline

("**Mastermind Merge**": Focuses on using `master` as the central axis for all development activities, streamlining the process)

#### Rationale:

- Aligned with [jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169672/git-merge-strategies-for-kanban-production-support-environment#comment136043663_77169672), eliminating the `develop` branch streamlines the workflow, and ensures that all development activities revolve around a single source of truth: the `master` branch.
- Incorporating the concept of "the point of commitment" from Kanban, as mentioned by jessehouwing, ensures that work merged into `master` is completed and tested.

#### CI/CD:

Trunk Based Development pairs well with CI/CD, as it encourages frequent merges to `master`.
That means your CI/CD pipeline can be configured to build and test whenever changes are pushed to `master`.

#### Environment:

- No need for a separate environment for each developer. A shared development environment should suffice, although you may use ephemeral environments for short-term testing before the merge.
- Developers create short-lived feature branches directly from `master`, effectively simplifying the branching model.
- These branches are merged back into `master` as soon as they are completed and have passed all necessary tests.

### 2. Feature Flags Combined with Trunk Based Development

("**Toggle Triumph**": Uses feature flags as a form of branching by abstraction, allowing for a more flexible and adaptive codebase.)

#### Rationale:

Incorporates jessehouwing's point about handling changing priorities and reducing the complexity by using feature flags. Feature flags can also be viewed as a form of "branching by abstraction," a strategy jessehouwing mentioned.

#### CI/CD:

Feature Flags can be controlled externally without code changes, allowing your CI/CD pipeline to remain straightforward.
Deployments can happen continuously, as new code can be introduced in a "toggled off" state and not affect the production behavior.

#### Environment:

- Again, there is no need for separate environments for each feature. Feature flags allow for the same codebase to behave differently depending on the environment, making it feasible to use a shared development environment.
- Developers incorporate feature flags in the code within `master`, allowing for features to be toggled on or off.
- That approach makes merging into `master` more streamlined, as jessehouwing suggested, by allowing features that are incomplete or of lower priority to be hidden or deactivated until they are ready.

### 3. Root Feature Branches in `master`

("**Root-and-Shoot**": Advocates for creating feature branches from `master` to keep a linear and clean commit history, making it easier to merge and deploy)

#### Rationale:

Takes into account [j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169672/git-merge-strategies-for-kanban-production-support-environment#comment136043641_77169672) to root feature branches in `master` rather than `develop`.
That would make it easier to merge these branches back into `master` and maintain a simpler commit history.

#### CI/CD:

Since feature branches are based on `master`, integrating them back is straightforward.
Your CI/CD pipeline can be configured to automatically build and test these feature branches before they are merged back into `master`.

#### Environment:

While a shared development environment could suffice, this strategy might benefit from temporary "feature environments" to test features in isolation before merging back into `master`.
However, these environments are not strictly necessary for each developer but could be beneficial for larger, more complex features.

#### Execution:

- In line with j6t's comment, feature branches are created from the latest stable commit in `master`.
- After thorough testing, these branches can be merged back into `master` without the need for cherry-picking, thereby keeping the commit history clean and straightforward.

---

All three strategies are compatible with a CI/CD workflow and do not necessitate a separate development environment for each feature branch, although the option is available in the "Root-and-Shoot" strategy if desired.
CI/CD can be configured to build and test based on activity in the `master` branch or individual feature branches, depending on the chosen strategy.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me/my job:

1. When you start development, you create your feature-branch from master-branch
2. When the work is finished, merge master branch into feature-branch (so it's 0 commits behind master, and some commits ahead)
3. run all testsuites
4. create pull request to master branch
5. code review and approve (if this step takes uncomfortably long, repeat step 2+3 before going to 6.)
6. merge into master
7. release from master branch

> how can we have a CICD branch with such a strategy...

Docker containers replicating production systems. At my job, we make extensive use of Docker containers to locally replicate production systems. (Right now we have 8 Docker containers running in parallel on dev laptops to simulate 8 different production systems)

> does each developer need a new development environment for each feature?

it's the same environment regardless of branch (with the exception of upgrading OS versions/docker configurations, eg `ubuntu 20.04=>22.04 branch` - in theory this means that we need to re-build the docker containers each time we switch from/to such a branch, but in practice the developer working on that branch just stays on that branch until it's merged into master. It's not often the docker configurations change anyway, maybe 4 times a year on average)

> What about features that build on top of other features, is there a good way to track such dependencies?

build on top of un-released features, you mean? lets say you have `master`, `feature-branch1` and want to create `feature-branch2` which depends on `feature-branch1`, fork `feature-branch2` from `feature-branch1` instead of `master`, then if `feature-branch2` is finished before `feature-branch1`, make the pull-request to the `feature-branch1` branch instead of `master` (but if feature-branch1 is merged to master before feature-branch2 is ready, then make the pull request to master) - in practice this rarely happens anyway (in my experience)